# Get Windows HDR status using Python win32api

Tags: python, windows, hdr

I’m looking for a way to get the HDR status on Windows using python. I’m aware of a way in C++ where we can use `IDXGIOutput6::GetDesc1()` to achieve this but how can I do this in python?